# select by specific value in sqlite?

Tags: android

i want to select data on the basis of bloodtype. suppose i want to select all 'A+' bloodtype in my table . what query will be applied.

```
public void selectbybloodtypes(){
 String s = "A+" ;
 String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "WHERE bloodtypes= '" + s ;

 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, String[] { });

 Contact contact = null;
 if (cursor.moveToFirst())
 {
     do
     {
         contact = new Contact();
         contact.setbloodtypes(cursor.getString(3));
            Log.d("getAllContacts()", contact.getBloodtypes().toString());
     }while(cursor.moveToNext());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the end quote for the query parameter, plus a space before the WHERE keyword. Should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE bloodtypes = '" + s + "'";
```

I would also recommend using any of the [`query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) methods instead of `rawQuery()`. They help avoid common mistakes.

Comment: 05-23 23:03:35.075: E/SQLiteLog(2079): (1) near "=": syntax error

Comment: @user3442104 A space before "WHERE" was also missing. All the more reason to use query()! :)

Comment: i have a value of bloodtype 'A+' saved in sharedpreferences and i want to select the data from the table on this basis.

Comment: @user3442104 Sorry, I did not understand that last question.

Comment: there value shown in textview in mainactivity . i want that  value to be called in dbhelper activity having a function . in this function i want to select all the record on the basis of the textview value